# Reading file in PERL using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi, activexobject

I have been trying to read a file in PERL using ActiveX Control. I was successful in reading the file using ActiveX Controls in HTML. So I changed the HTML code to PERL cgi using "Print" Statement. After that I am not able to read the file the file using ActiveX, other JavaScript functions are working good.

```
print "<script src='/EnvelopeUtility/EnvelopeJS.js'></script>";
```

Above line of code is used to invoke the external JavaScript.

```
print "<td><input type='button' name='btn1' value='Process' onClick='getData(document.getElementById('sampleFile').value)'></td>";
```

Above line of code is an button in HTML, which onClick invokes the JavaScript method getdata()

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
```

Above line of code is present in external JavaScript which creates an ActiveX Object to read the file.

```
    readFile = obj.OpenTextFile(path, 1, false);
                while(!readFile.AtEndOfStream) 
                {
        readFile = obj.OpenTextFile(path, 1, false);
.................
```

Above line of code is the one which reads the file line be line.

The above code is working fine in HTML but in CGI after using print statement am not able to read the file. Please do suggest what should be changed in order to read the file.

Comment: Is the file available for the user that runs the webserver?

Comment: You are generating HTML using Perl/CGI. The browser still gets HTML. There is no difference at all from the browser's POV from loading a static HTML file from a server and loading one dynamically generated using Perl/CGI. Whatever the problem is, you've misdiagnosed the cause.

Comment: [There is no such thing as PERL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f)

Comment: I believe not, I am trying to read the file from the client system. Would it be accessible using ActiveX Object?

Comment: You said it was before, so presumably - yes. (Unless you've changed other things about the page, such as putting it in a different security zone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a simple HTML error.

```
onClick='getData(document.getElementById('sampleFile').value)'
```

Your attribute value is delimited by `'` characters, but you try to use literal `'` characters as raw data inside the attribute.

Consequently the value of the attribute becomes `getData(document.getElementById(` which isn't valid JavaScript.

This would have been picked up if you had used a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

If you want to use a `'` as data in an attribute value delimited by `'` then you have to represent it as `&#39;`.

Comment: 'sampleFile' in the above case is the id <input type='file' id='sampleFile'>

So in this case how should I pass the input to the javascript?

Comment: @Babu — Assuming you want to use the non-standard ActiveX approach you were taking before … you fix the syntax errors in your HTML as described in the last sentence of this answer.